# Error "$queryOptions is not a valid argument to updateUser" is returned when create a new user by using the mgo package

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

One my MongoDB client program has been working well for a MongoDB 3.2 master-slave cluster for a long time.
But now, a problem shows up when it connects to a MongoDB 3.0.2 sharding cluster.

When the program creates a new user for a new database, the error "$queryOptions is not a valid argument to updateUser" is always returned at the following code:

```
    err = newdb.UpsertUser(&mgo.User{
        Username: newusername,
        Password: newpassword,
        Roles: []mgo.Role{
            mgo.RoleReadWrite,
        },
    })
```

Can anyone provide some hints?

btw, the mgo package is the latest one.

Comment: This seems like an incompatibility between latest mgo and MongoDB 3.0.2. You can [file a bug report](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues) with mgo project.

Comment: @Adrian, thanks for the response. I will fill an issue there.